# i7 7700 temprature spikes

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, intel, overheating, fan

Im using Ubuntu 16.04 on my computer, but i've noticed that my fans are constantly spinning up quite high. First I was only annoyed by the sound, but now i've started monitoring the tempatures of the CPU. It seems that the cores themselves are not too hot (37 degrees) but every once in a while it starts spiking up to 63 for a second, before going back to about 37 degrees.

I've tried upgrading my kernel from 4.8 to 4.9 with a little bit of improvement, but it's still way worse than in Windows.

My specs are:

I7 7700
16gb ram
GTX 1080 (proprietary Nvidia driver, nvidia-381.22)

Output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'`:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1b80 (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device 3362
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_381, nvidia_381_drm
```

Comment: Did you install Nvidia drivers?

Comment: Yeah sorry, I just realized I forgot to add that. I'm using the proprietary Nvidia drivers (nvidia-381.22).

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 done. I'm not sure if the issue is because of my GPU though. The fan noise seems to keep going with nomodeset enabled too.

Comment: Oh, this is a desktop with only discrete graphics. I don't think it is related either.

Comment: Upgrading from 4.8 to 4.9 isn't a great leap I think I'm runn 4.11.3  on my laptop (on phone now)

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I might try upgrading to 4.11. I have tried 4.10 before, but then I get a black flickering screen at boot (seems to conflict with the display driver)

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix same happens in 4.11. The computer boots, goes to the splash screen and then starts flickering. It seems that the computer isn´t totally locked as I can still access the TTY.

Comment: @Jeroen have you read the threads here dealing with Skylake processors, Kabylake, etc? Are you using Thermald and Powerclamp? For my IvyBridge I have those two plus I use TLP for controlling fan speed based on CPU  Temp. TLP used in conjunction with the first two really helped smooth things out. I used to run 70c, 80c, 90c, etc. Now it's 40c, 50c and 60c instead. Oops just read you are on desktop. Not sure how relevant my comments are in that case.